# Designing my own list in django and bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-templates, django-views, django-bootstrap3

Hi I'm pretty new to django and bootstrap. 
I would like to know if there is a way to create a custom list items.

For example, I have my User class in models, I would like to show all users in a list that each item contains user fields such as image, name, age.

The questions are:

1. How do I design a single list item and then reuse it for all items in the list?
2. How do I use the model and fill the list from its fields?
   (example : for each user in users, set image to user.image, set text1 to user.name, set text2 to user.age)

Thanks for the helpers in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview). It will provide a context variable for your template called `object_list` that will contain your list. There is absolutely no need to copy the values from the model objects into some intermediary item class. There never is.

```py
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class UserListView(ListView):

    model = User  # your user model
```

By default this will use the template `yourapp/user_list.html` but you can override it by setting the class variable `template_name` in the UserListView class.

There's not more to it. That's why Django rocks. Many newcomers make mistakes and complicate things because they don't realize how powerful Django really is and how little code you need to write.